# Sort arraylist of arrays based on two prioritized elements

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of arrays, which I want to sort based on the arrays' two integers. I want to sort them based on a primary integer in descending order, then sort them based on one another secondary integer existing in arrays in ascending order, while maintaining the first order.

Say I have an array1 with [1, 3]; array2 with [1, 1]; array3 with [0, 50].

At first, they are unsorted in the ArrayList array1, array2 and array3.
After sorting they are in order as follows: array2, array1, and array3.

Comment: OK. but your question body is just a description for a challenge. what's your question?

Comment: We love that you're here an we need your code so we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

you can sort the list by `Collections.sort`.

```
public void sort(List<Integer[]> list)
     return Collections.sort(list, (o1, o2) -> o1[0].equals(o2[0]) ? o1[1] - o2[1] : o1[0] - o2[0]);
}
```

we use Lambda expression to compare to `Integer[]`

when you want to sort two `Integer` (A,B) descendingly, you must compare them like `B-A` and if you want to sort ascendingly, you should use `A-B`

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner with java8

```
list.stream().sorted((prim, sec) -> prim[0] == sec[0] ? prim[1] - sec[1] : prim[0] - sec[0]).collect(Collectors.toList());
```